# What is the purpose of predict in extracting features in cnn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i have made a cnn using keras.

Now i wanted to extract features of my train set from this model. I compiled the model and trained it on the train set first. Then i used the 'predict; to extract features of the train set. Following lines of code used.

```
     train_feature = model.predict(X_TRAIN)
     print(train_feature.shape) # (692,10)
```

692 are the total train images. Now what does 10 represent? I had 10 classes. What is 10 representing over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't called "*extracting features*". So you **shouldn't** assign to this name:

```
train_feature = model.predict(X_TRAIN)  # I suggest train_output or something
```

The number of columns, ie 10, is the number of categories you have, assuming you built your model properly. Each of the 10 categories will result in a probability when making a forward pass.

Comment: OK Thanks, Can you share some useful link to extract features of the train set using the model, if u know any?

Comment: That would be against site rules, sorry. But I guess it's okay if it's coming from the official documentation: https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/